# Can't install bundle - endless error message

Tags: bundle, bundler, drush

This is what I'm using: Windows 8. Cygwin32. Rvm version 1.25.27. Ruby version 2.1.2p95. Gem version 2.3.0. Drush version 5.9.

I'm totally new to all this so it's very possible that the explanation is something really simple.

I tried to use "drush omega-guard" from my drupal theme folder but got an error saying I had to install Bundler version 1.2 or newer. This is all fine since I hadn't installed bundle. But when I try to use the command "bundle install" I get this:

```
    $ bundle install
-bash: bundle: kommandot finns inte
```

(Kommandot finns inte = Command not found.) 
When I try using "gem bundler install" I get this:

```
 $ gem bundler install
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command bundler
```

I also tried "gem bundle install":

```
$ gem bundle install
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command bundle
```

So I used "which bundle" and then used cd to get to that folder.

```
$ which bundle
/home/I/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/bundle
```

I tried the same commands again, but from the other folder, and ended up with this:

```
I@I ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin
$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String

I@I ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin
$ gem install bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String

I@I ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin
$ bundle install
/home/I/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:313:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 13 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/I/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2:/home/I/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global', execute `gem env` for more information
        from /home/I/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:322:in `to_spec'
        from /home/I/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
        from /home/I/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

When I use command "gem list" bundle isn't listed:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.5, 1.2.4)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (5.3.5, 4.7.5)
psych (2.0.5)
rake (10.3.2, 10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.1, 4.1.0)
test-unit (2.5.5, 2.1.2.0)
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? I have been following this tutorial and everything has worked fine up until this point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XF_LaSfua8Y&index=10&list=PLLnpHn493BHH5nnK2dKE_42l1oXA6Tq6H

**EDIT:** Since I asked this question I tried reinstalling ruby 2.1.2. The installation stuck on "#importing gemset" and after about 36 hours my computer was turned of due to a blackout. I therefore don't know if the reinstallation was completed or not. After that I also changed my gem version to 2.1.2 to match the ruby version. Theese things seemed to help and afterwards I could run both "gem install bundler" and "bundle install". My gemlist now looks like this:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

addressable (2.3.6)
bigdecimal (1.2.5, 1.2.4)
breakpoint (2.0.7)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.6.3)
celluloid (0.15.2)
chunky_png (1.3.1)
coderay (1.1.0)
color-schemer (0.2.8)
compass (0.12.6)
compass-blend-modes (0.0.2)
compass-normalize (1.5)
compass-rgbapng (0.2.1)
compass-validator (3.0.1)
css_parser (1.3.5)
dash (0.4.0)
fssm (0.2.10)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (5.3.5, 4.7.5)
psych (2.0.5)
rake (10.3.2, 10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.1, 4.1.0)
sass (3.2.19)
test-unit (2.5.5, 2.1.2.0)
timers (1.1.0)
```

But a new problem occur when I try running "drush omega-guard":

```
$ drush omega-guard
Which theme do you want to run Guard for?
 [0]  :  Cancel
 [1]  :  Ohm (Subtheme of Omega) - Omega based demonstration theme. Serves as a
         best-practice reference for the Omega documentation. Ohm will be
         constantly updated as best practice evolves so shouldn't be used in
         production.
 [2]  :  Omega - A powerful HTML5 base theme framework utilizing tools like
         Sass, Compass, Grunt, Bower, Ruby Version Manager, Bundler and more.
 [3]  :  Design (Subtheme of Omega) - Please provide a description for
         your theme.

3
There was a problem with your setup:                                 [error]
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler can't satisfy your Gemfile's dependencies.
Install missing gems with `bundle install`.
```

So I try using the command "bundle install" again but end up with an endless error message:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using addressable 2.3.6
Using chunky_png 1.3.1
Using fssm 0.2.10
Using sass 3.2.19
Using compass 0.12.6
Using breakpoint 2.0.7
Using timers 1.1.0
Using celluloid 0.15.2
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using compass-blend-modes 0.0.2
Using color-schemer 0.2.8
Using compass-normalize 1.5
Using compass-rgbapng 0.2.1
Using compass-validator 3.0.1
Using css_parser 1.3.5
      0 [main] ruby 15100 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'fcntl.so' (0x620000) is already occupied
      0 [main] ruby 11364 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'fcntl.so' (0x620000) is already occupied
      1 [main] ruby 14584 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'fcntl.so' (0x620000) is already occupied
```

The last three lines keep on repeating forever but with different numbers. So what is the problem this time?

Answer (score 0):

Drush is a PHP app, not an Ruby one.

You need a PHP work environment (at first an PHP cli) to work with drush.

Comment: I got xampp installed and when i write "which php" i get: $ which php
/cygdrive/c/xampp/php/php
So i guess that's not the problem?